# lset not working properly

Tags: list, tcl

I have this issue with a lset command in my script. Wheter I issue the command to replace a specific values in the list, I end up displaying all the element of the list.

```
lset gamma_aa [expr int($index)] 0
```

instead of changing $index's value in the list to a 0 value will display the whole list in the command windows!
the List was created a single list using lrepeat

```
set gamma_aa [lrepeat [expr int($nbrx*$nbry)] 0.]
```

Did I miss something?

Comment: That's how lset works. It changes one element and returns the whole (updated) list value.

Comment: Oh, thanks for the info!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `lset` command returns the new contents of the list, much as `set` returns the new contents of a variable. You can (usually) ignore that return value.

The actual setting of the value at that particular index should have happened. It might be hard to see if the value you've set it to is not particularly distinct from what was held at that index previously, or if the indexed position is a long way from the start of the list.

---

Also, you really don't need to do:

```
lset gamma_aa [expr int($index)] 0
```

This should work as well in all sane cases:

```
lset gamma_aa $index 0
```